# How to import an external .cpp and .h files from a saperate directory in a ros node?

Tags: ros, catkin

I have a simple ros node inside a catkin package. Now i want to include a .h along with another .cpp file in my node. The .h and .cpp files are part of another directory which is not part of the catkin package that has this nodes. So I believe I need to add the external directory in my package's cmake lists but I am not sure how. Can anyone help me how ? Should I also link targets of the .h files ?

Answer (score 2):

catkin is just an extension of CMake, so you can use the standard CMake commands to solve your problem.

First, you need to add the include directory ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)) like:

```
include_directories(${YOUR_DIRECTORY})
```

Defining the source files can be done by setting a variable ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html))

```
set(EXT_SOURCES
  ${YOUR_DIRECTORY}/file.cpp
)
```

using these source files at your node libaray ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html)) and / or node ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html)) executable:

```
add_library(library_name ${EXT_SOURCES})
add_executable(node_executable_name ${EXT_SOURCES})
```