# Combining two CMakeLists.txt file (ROS and Libtorch)

Tags: cmake, ros, libtorch

I am trying to combine two CMakeLists.txt files to compile a C++ program that has both ROS and Libtorch dependencies. The individual files are provided below:

Libtorch CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

# The following code block is suggested to be used on Windows.
# According to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25457,
# the DLLs need to be copied to avoid memory errors.
if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET example-app
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:example-app>)
endif (MSVC)
```

I found this here: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html

ROS CMakeListis.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(fly_bot_cpp)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  tf
  gazebo_msgs
)

include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

The program example-app.cpp has both libraries of ROS and LibTorch.

So here is what i tried to do:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(fly_bot_cpp)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="home/jarvis/libtorch;/opt/ros/melodic")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  tf
  rospy
  message_generation
)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(test_quad src/test_quad.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_quad ${catkin_LIBRARIES} "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")

set_property(TARGET test_quad PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

The code test_quad.cpp (previously referred to as example-app.cpp) contains ros header files and torch header files:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <torch/torch.h>
.
.
.
```

However, I get the following error.

```
fatal error: torch/torch.h: No such file or directory
 #include <torch/torch.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Can someone please help me out??

Thank you so much.

Comment: The most direct approach would be compining lines from the two `CMakeLists.txt` into the one `CMakeLists.txt`. Have you tried that? What is you **problem**?

Comment: Please show what you've already tried and whats the exact problem with it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sir, I have edited my post. I am a newbie to CMake so please forgive me if I have done anything silly. Thank you so much for your precious time.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Sir, I have edited my post. Thank you so much for your precious time.

Comment: Example of using tourch sets `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable, but your `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't contain this setting.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059478/how-to-import-an-external-cpp-and-h-files-from-a-saperate-directory-in-a-ros-n/61076513#61076513  - this should almoust solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} in your target_link_libraries.
The line should look like this

> target_link_libraries(test_quad ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})

This should resolve the torch header.

Please also take a look at this post to find some more answers to where you might get stuck in the future-https://answers.ros.org/question/347885/combining-cmakeliststxt-of-libtorch-and-cmakeliststxt-of-ros-package/#

I hope this answer is helpful to someone new coming onboard to ros and libtorch :)